# Is There A Way To Only Copy Specific Columns From RedShift To S3 Using RedShiftCopyActivity?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I assume that copying from RedShift -> S3 can only be done with RedshiftcCopyActivity. However I can't seem to find a way to copy only specific columns to S3 (only copy all columns).

The reason I am doing this because one of the columns in the redshift contains carriage return character that messing up with PigActivity defined later on. So I figure since I don't need that column I will just copy only the columns to make my PigActivity runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use transformSql option in RedshiftCopyActivity to copy selective columns.
ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html

Comment: you're right ... it took me a while to realize that what I need is transformSql. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe RedshiftCopyActivity is used for the utilizing `COPY` command which is S3->Redshift. The opposite command is `UNLOAD`.

Your request can be done with SQLActivity where you can write complete `UNLOAD` command using `SELECT` statement to define columns for unload.